# How to sed or grep value between two characters pdf

Tags: python, linux, grep

I want to copy and write to a file a value between two characters in a pdf file using sed or grep but can't work out how to do this. String I want to copy is e.g., *nnnn/yyyy* nnnn is a number value that can change and yyyy is a year value that can change. Example:

```
23/2019
5014/2020
1117/2015
1/2020
```

I also need to copy and write the alpha numeric value on the line before either '&' and/or '('. That value is broken with a space.

The following is how the data is converted from pdf to text

```
United States of America    TXCO fuel management

Where 3315 Fredericksburg Rd, San Antonio, TX 78201                             (Pump 7), 
United States
()

3136CACE816877B17EABF2527E712B2D366DF F8C3FD6B1B33B11B733B49A9364 (771) & 7A5261C640D69CAD968B1F1C8CEEFC17D2C73947723A9B462D8ABC10D881F933 

 DD6052F67258F2B789010E834D711192914834CD3688E4260A7B52D2A9 373A75 (5009) & 8E5767F7092BA7E8FC6706EFC7FBC58E3E965F5F608978A484DE0CFF68D13C5E 

(SRIM/74/2020) (via link) 

B251A8C6C649725306C725BCA23E7C211A63 95BDF1747F9F30B43155E3B7A8A8 & 4796F04682E1B30C704AE3A4530FE51D913C5C3181F19418A07259CFDA0E05DD

(OGAR/83/2020) (via link) 

801742B10E6CB8E E31E0FC508B6550D8C7766B42EEFA052D3F678D59DBF99655 & 1D873ED80DC020BC75C1E52B20E9F08E6E6C58F140F74DFD18B726856FD394A8
(IND/3/2020) (via link) 

Upload 11.00990                                               9:00 AM

Upload tr11.09907                                               9:00 AM

Upload jud 11 uur8                                              9:00 AM

Upload loc10 11                                              9:00 AM

File: TCXO 5g aa, TXCO 5g yy, TXCO 5g an8     

Pump inventory &&& management
Fuel
Type
Sale
&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&& .. 
"\*w " &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&
len()
```

Some lines of text may have another (text) before the text I want to copy, but will not have the string (nnnn/yyyy).

So the line has text before "nnnn" that I want to ignore, also want to ignore the first "/" and also ignore any text after ")" Basically I just want to copy and write everything between "/" and the first ")" after the "/" character

I think that I can install the package pdfgrep, then use the command:

```
find /path -iname '*.pdf' -exec pdfgrep pattern {} +
```

But I don't know how to set the pattern. Is there a way I can grep for only this string *nnnn/yyyy*?

I read that I can use python to convert the pdf to text but not sure about how to do that yet?

All consideration, ideas or other appreciated  =)

Comment: please edit your Q to include your sample output from the sample input. `grep -o regex file.pdf > file.txt` may be all you need, but can't be sure now. Good luck.

Comment: grep -o regex file.pdf > file.txt yields nothing. When I checked with #ls -als and more commands, the output was 0 bytes and an empty file